# A hotel booking algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am working a problem with hotel booking. Here is my question.

1. If I book a one day room, it will cost me $200.
2. If I book a 7 day continuous room, it will cost me $700.

I know which days in a month I will travel, assume I input it as an array:

```
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 3;
a[2] = 4;
a[3] = 5;
a[4] = 10;
```

Then I should book a room for 7 days (1st - 7th) and a one day (10th) room, which will cost me $900.

Is there any algorithm I can use to determine how I should book the hotel based on the array I input?

Comment: Hint: The cutover point is 4 days in any 7. Make a start on this then come back with any specific questions. By then I hope you will have picked the implementation language.

Comment: Sounds like dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a dynamic programming solution:

**Input**

- array containing arrival days for travel, `A` of size `N`
- rate for staying for one day: `RATE_DAY`
- rate for staying for one week (7 days or fewer): `RATE_WEEK`

**Optimal subproblems**

The problem of finding the minimum cost for day `A[i]` is equivalent to the minimum over:

- The minimum cost for `A[i-1]` + `RATE_DAY`
- The minimum cost for `A[i-2]` + `RATE_WEEK` (if possible)
- The minimum cost for `A[i-3]` + `RATE_WEEK` (if possible)
- ...
- The minimum cost for `A[i-7]` + `RATE_WEEK` (if possible)

In less formal terms, the optimal solution for the next day is to either take another day rate, or group it with a weekly rate, comparing each of the 7 possible groupings for weekly rates such that the current day is part of that grouping. The "(if possible)" part indicates that such a comparison should only be made if `A[i-j]` falls within the same 7 day interval with `A[i]` (they both fit in a single week).

This is a top-down dynamic programming approach.

I wrote a small program in C++ to demonstrate:

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d16a9b98a5f224f)

Comment: I have a little confusion here. Why do you think we should calculate "A[i-2] + RATE_WEEK" instead of "A[i-2] + 2*RATE_DAY"?

Comment: Oh, I got it. We have calculated A[i-2] + RATE_DAY when get A[i-1], thus A[i-2] + 2*RATE_DAY must be no less than A[i-1] + RATE_DAY. Thanks, AndyG!

Comment: @MarvinWang: Really glad to help. One of my assumptions was that `RATE_DAY < RATE_WEEK`, so `A[i-1] + RATE_DAY < A[i-1] + RATE_WEEK`. The reason I tested `A[i-2] + RATE_WEEK` was because I was attempting to group `A[i]` and `A[i-1]` into the same week period. An interesting result is that, if `A[i-1]` was already being grouped into a week before, then the algorithm is actually considering paying a weekly rate twice for that day! Of course, this should be suboptimal and the DP shouldn't choose such an ordering.